# ¿Como detectar si dos columnas tienen una relacion de muchos a muchos en sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en un excel donde hay dos columnas llamadas CEN_EDU (nombre de un colegio)y Director(director de un colegio). Lo que yo queria es que mediante una consulta SQL revisar si un director puede ser director de varios colegios y si un colegio puede tener varios directores. Ya que revisar esto a ojo me tardaria mucho pues son muchos registros.

Lo que intente fue esto:

```
SELECT 
    DIRECTOR, CEN_EDU, COUNT(*)
FROM
    padron_web
WHERE
    DIRECTOR IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CEN_EDU, DIRECTOR
```

Lo que crei que pasaria es que con el GROUP BY CEN_EDU, eliminaria los colegios duplicados y que con GROUP BY DIRECTOR eliminaria los colegios duplicados dentro del subgrupo del colegio. Por lo tanto, en el count(*) me saldria mas de 1 si un colegio tiene mas de 1 director, pero revisando un dato vi que un colegio tenia en la columna count(*) un valor de 3 pero el director era la misma persona solo que se repetia 3 veces en el mismo colegio.

Espero que mi duda se entienda y puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, como comentas y tal como has planteado tu solución, estás calculando cuántas veces el mismo director dirige cada colegio. Es decir, básicamente estás detectando duplicados.

Lo que realmente buscas es aún más sencillo:

- Los directores que dirigen cada colegio lo obtienes agrupando por centro:

> ```
> SELECT 
>     CEN_EDU, COUNT(*)
> FROM
>     padron_web
> WHERE
>     DIRECTOR IS NOT NULL
> GROUP BY CEN_EDU
> ```

- Y, los centros que dirige cada director, agrupando por director:

> ```
> SELECT 
>     DIRECTOR, COUNT(*)
> FROM
>     padron_web
> WHERE
>     DIRECTOR IS NOT NULL
> GROUP BY DIRECTOR
> ```

Añade al final de cada query un `HAVING COUNT(*)>1` para quedarte con los casos que quieres detectar.

Si quieres eliminar duplicados, es mucho más eficiente `DISTINCT`. Utiliza `GROUP BY` únicamente si quieres aplicar alguna función de totales: `SUM()`, `COUNT()`, `AVG()`, etc.

Por otra parte, deducir la cardinalidad a través de unos datos de muestra, te puede inducir a error. Que en tus datos no haya ningún director que dirija dos centros, no implica necesariamente que no pueda llegar a existir. Deberías fijar la cardinalidad en función de la normativa y, ante la duda, presuponer que ese caso puede llegar a darse. Es más sencillo fijar una restricción más adelante que tener que modificar tu modelo en el futuro para tener en cuenta esa posibilidad.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Answer (score -1):

esa es una pregunta muy fácil, por dos razones

### Primera

Las instituciones solo tienen un rector o también llamado director, bueno si cuentas al subrector/subdirector como el rector entonces si tiene dos, pero solo tienen uno.

### Segunda

si tienes una relación n*m eso quiere decir que forzosamente para que A y B tengan una relación de muchos a muchos o mejor dicho de muches a muches
debe de existir C para que en C pongas los registros en los que hay relación.

### Ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`dept_emp` y `dept_manager` tienen una relacion muches a muches por medio de `departaments`

supongamos que si existe A, B y C

```sql
CREATE TABLE departments (
    dept_manager_id   INT NOT NULL,
    dept_emp_id       INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dept_manager (
   id INT NOT NULL,
   dept_no CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
   from_date    DATE            NOT NULL,
   to_date      DATE            NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (emp_no)  REFERENCES employees (emp_no)    ON DELETE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments (dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,dept_no)
); 

CREATE TABLE dept_emp (
    id      INT             NOT NULL,
    dept_no     CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE            NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no)  REFERENCES employees   (emp_no)  ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments (dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,dept_no)
);
```

### Query

para obtener los datos de una relación de muchos a muchos, necesitamos algo como lo siguiente.

```sql
SELECT a.campo as campoA, b.campo as compoB
FROM A as a
INNER JOIN C as c ON a.id = c.aId;
INNER JOIN B as b ON c.bId = b.id;
```